# How to update a particular row of a particular column to reflect values in another table through PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables with some columns:

1. items

   1. item_id

      1. 9ef3b1e2-b0d3-480a-ba60-3616712d68f1
      2. 11111111-b0d3-480a-ba60-3616712d68f1
   2. item_data_id

      1. fd55b8c5-ebf9-5e6d-8d73-8b63111d5196
      2. 22222222-ebf9-5e6d-8d73-8b63111d5196
2. item_data

   1. item_data_id

      1. null
      2. null
   2. item_id

      1. 9ef3b1e2-b0d3-480a-ba60-3616712d68f1
      2. 11111111-b0d3-480a-ba60-3616712d68f1

Table one already contains values for item_id and table two already contains values for item_data_id and item_id filled with unique IDs (where the item_id values for both already match). How do I update items.item_data_id (table 1) to reflect the values already present in item_data.item_data_id (table 2) without updating every row in the column of table 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a join as

```
update items 
set item_data_id  = item_data.item_data_id 
from item_data 
where  items.item_id = item_data.item_id
```